# Vertically aligning a checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, vertical-alignment

I have looked at the different questions regarding this issue, but couldn't find anything that works due to limitations in my markup.

My markup looks like so (unfortunately as this is generated by some backend, I am unable to change the markup).

```
<ul>        
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="test[]" id="myid1">
        <label for="myid1">label1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="test[]" id="myid2">
        <label for="myid2">label1</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need the checkbox to be on the right and centered vertically in the `<li>`

Currently, this is styled as:

```
li input{
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I have tried using various values for `vertical-align`, but that doesn't seem to help. Also, in some cases the label can be very long and span multiple lines. The checkbox would still need to be able to vertically center itself when the height of the li is arbitrary.

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: Would prefer not to :) Forgot to mention that the markup is generated by a backend, so I can't really use tables in my markup.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Vertical alignment only works on inline elements. If you float it, then I don't think it is treated as part of that stream of inline elements any more.

Make the label an inline-block, and use vertical alignment on both the label and the input to align their middles. Then, assuming it is okay to have a specific width on the labels and checkboxes, use relative positioning instead of floating to swap them ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zcuLgbxt/)):

```
input {
    width: 20px;

    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
         
    vertical-align: middle;
}

label {  
    width: 200px;
    
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

2024 update, using Flexbox ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ycg0kdb/)):

```
ul {
  width: 300px; /* Only for demonstration. */
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Only needed for swapping their order. */
    align-items: center;
}

input {
    background-color: blue;
}

label {
    background-color: red;
    flex-grow: 1; /* Grow the label to fill available space, pushing the checkboxes to the edge of the container. */
}
```

Less hacky, and with this you don't need to specify any widths. It will grow to fill the container, and wrap if necessary.

Another alternative would be Flexbox Grid.

Comment: Thanks so much, for me the key point was "use vertical alignment on both the label and the input", I was using it only on the input.. Thanks again!

Comment: The key to this is that the label width forces the wrapping.  If the ul width forces the wrapping.  Having a width on the label is mandatory.

Answer (score 13):

Its not a perfect solution, but a good workaround.

You need to assign your elements to behave as table with `display: table-cell`

#### Solution: <sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/xaWy2/3/)</sup>

HTML:

```
<ul>        
    <li>
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="test[]" id="myid1"></div>
        <div><label for="myid1">label1</label></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="test[]" id="myid2"></div>
        <div><label for="myid2">label2</label></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 4):

The most effective solution that I found is to define the parent element with `display:flex` and `align-items:center`

[LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=834aa126-8474-47d2-bdf9-ca951de39be3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      .myclass{
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        background-color:grey;
        color:#fff;
        height:50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="myclass">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>do you love Ananas?
      </label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: did we use the height of parent?

Answer (score 1):

```css
Add CSS:


li {
  display: table-row;
 
 }
li div {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;

  }
.check{
  width:20px;

  }
ul{
   list-style: none;
  }
```

```html
 <ul>
       <li>

           <div><label for="myid1">Subject1</label></div>
            <div class="check"><input type="checkbox" value="1"name="subject" class="subject-list" id="myid1"></div>
       </li>
       <li>

           <div><label for="myid2">Subject2</label></div>
              <div class="check" ><input type="checkbox" value="2"  class="subject-list" name="subjct" id="myid2"></div>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <img src="/image.png" />
</div>
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    margin-top: -50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works reliably for me.  Cell borders and height added for effect and clarity:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right; border: thin solid; height:50px">Some label:</td>
    <td style="border: thin solid;">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="chk1" style="cursor:pointer; "><label for="chk1" style="margin-top:auto; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:auto; cursor:pointer;">Check Me</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd recommend to separate inline CSS, otherwise the answer is difficult to follow

Answer (score -2):

make input to block and float, Adjust margin top value.

HTML:

```
<div class="label">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" /> luke..
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*
change margin-top, if your line-height is different.
*/
input[type=checkbox]{
height:18px;
width:18px;
padding:0;
margin-top:5px;
display:block;
float:left;
}
.label{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tsecheng/N7Puv/)