# Line up these custom checkboxes and labels

Tags: css, checkbox, vertical-alignment, sizing

The CSS styled these spans to be the same height as the containing label, `2vw`

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        padding-left:3vw;
        height:2vw;
        line-height:2vw;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
        background:lime;
        color:lime;
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:-3vw;
        text-align:center;
        width:2vw;
        height:2vw;
}
```

[image]

But they are clearly not.

Also, the span is not vertically centered.

What is missing in order to make the spans both the *same height as* and *vertically centered within* the containing labels?

Fiddle you this : http://jsfiddle.net/zLU8r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long period of research and reflection it appears

[This answer works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815560/907415)

Give the span a 
`display: inline-block;` and vertical-alignment can work.