# Align Checkboxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to align my checkboxes in my site and I did some search over the stackoverflow and I found some solution that couldn't help me to align me checkboxes as I want. The [first solution-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers) and the [second solution-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815328/vertically-aligning-a-checkbox).

My checkboxes look like the image below...

[image]

The **RED** line is where I want all my checkboxes to be.

Here is the code for my checkboxes...

```
    <label id="Disease">Disease:</label><br />
    <!--emfanizei tis epiloges gia ta diseases me basi auta p exoume sti basi mas -->
    <?php
  $sql = "SELECT name FROM disease";
  $query_resource = mysql_query($sql);
  while( $name = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource) ):
?>
    <span><?php echo $name['name']; ?></span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>" /><br />

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your site:

```
label#Disease ~ span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}
```

That's giving the sibling `span`s that follow your `label#Disease` element a set width, which will push all the checkboxes to the right.

Play with the width to get it to your desired size, making sure you don't have text overflow or other issues.

Comment: Thank you that works fine , I will accept you answer as soon as possible because I needs some time in order to accept an answer

Comment: @DogFace – Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 2):

Why not wrap the inputs in labels, then float them to the right hand side? The advantage being you then are using the semantic `label` element instead of `span`, and can toggle the checkbox with a click on both the text and the `input`

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<label>Label
  <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" />
</label>
<label>Label
  <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" />
</label>
<label>Label
  <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" />
</label>
<label>Label
  <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" />
</label>
<label>Label
  <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" />
</label>
<label>Label
  <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" />
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time :) I will try your solution just to see if it works because I already accept the other answer . Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `text-align:right` css rule to the wrapper of the checkboxes.

Or, you can put the checkboxes into table cells like this:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>labelsdfsdf</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>label</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>label</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>labelsdf sdfsdfsdf</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>label</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```