# Print Checkboxes list vertically

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, html-table, spring-form

How can I print the checkbox list vertically?

Currently, it is printing horizontally as shown below.

Subject 1 Subject 2 Subject 3 Subject 4 Subject 5

I want it this way

Subject 2
Subject 4
Subject 5

Here is the code I am using to print it.

```
 <tr>
 <td>
 <form:checkboxes items="${favouriteList}" path="subjects" ></form:checkboxes>
 </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically aligning a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815328/vertically-aligning-a-checkbox)

Comment: Yes it does answere